# Polynomial division code

Tags: polynom

I would like to give me an example of how to use the `polynom` package. More specifically, I want to write down on my latex editor the following polynomial division ([source](http://davidlowryduda.com/?p=619)):

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you know that you can [right-click on the code and show the actual TeX behind it](http://i.stack.imgur.com/wV5dz.png) (since it's written in MathJax)?

Comment: It may not be pretty, but [this is the code used by MathJax](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Km6x4.png)...

Comment: Are you interested in reproducing the example as-is with/without `polynom`, or whatever it takes...?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like people did not sure whether this is a "do for me" question or you are asking anything else. Let me start to clarify something...

First you mentions `polynom`, which is good at creating long division

[image]

with relatively easy code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polynom}
\begin{document}
    \polylongdiv{X^3-12X^2-42}{X-3}
\end{document}
```

But its output is relatively difficult to modify since it is hard-coded using `tabular` internally. You would need to rewrite the output scheme. If it is not the desired, the remaining problem is whether you prefer `polynom`'s default output or the **cross** one you provide?

Second, `Mathjax`, though extremely convenient over HTML, uses its own engine. It supports small amount of packages by rewriting them case by case. (Which may save some resources since one does not need line-breaking/page-breaking/etc anymore.) Thus it is hard to create a consistent user experience between `MathJax` and `polynom`, a probably-will-never-support package. You might either

- Concentrate on LaTeX and use htlatex to convert to HTML
- Write `Mathjax`-friendly syntax in your LaTeX file
- Work on both LaTeX and `MathJax` and adopt that they are not not going to be the same.

Comment: Is there any option `polylongadd`, `polylongsub`, `polylongmul` like `polylongdiv` in polynom packaage.

Comment: For doing https://ibb.co/gW1zio