# Polynomial long division in Beamer

Tags: beamer

I have searched the forum for polynomial long division displaying terms like 0x and found a great solution but it does not work in Beamer. Any help would be appreciated.

The code I found was at [Polynomial division code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/174318/polynomial-division-code?rq=1) but it does not seem to work for me in beamer. How do I paste the code i here? I get an error message when I try.

Comment: Welcome to the site.  Perhaps you could edit your question to provide a minimum working example of what you find works in another document class.  It would help get us all started on something more than a hypothetical.

Comment: Come on! let us not welcome a new comer with a down vote. Please be kind.

Comment: Well, what have you tried? Can you show us the code?  And please give us a link to the great solution you found here ...We need more informations to be able to help you!

Comment: The code I found was at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/174318/polynomial-division-code?rq=1

Comment: Thanks. My problem is trying to display terms such as 0X. Tim

Answer (score 4):

The following works fine with Beamer. You probably did not use the 'fragile' option on the frame.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{polynom}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
    \polylongdiv{X^3-12X^2-42}{X-3}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Works fine for me even without `fragile`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT.  You're right.  Now I really wonder what the OP's problem was.